# Templating engine that render only the model changes

Tags: knockout.js, angularjs, template-engine, jquery-templates

Is there any templating js library that can render only the changes in the model instead of the whole model.
Ex: If the model is an array of data type
[{
  Name:'1'
  Address:'2'
},
{
  Name:'3'
  Address:'4'
}]

Initially the framework will render the data as html view.
When I change the model (add new element in the array) I want only the changes(the new element) to be rendered instead of re-rendering the whole model.

I've tried KnockoutJS but when the model change the whole view is re-rendered instead only the change.

Comment: AngularJS will, most of the time, update only DOM nodes that are bound to model expressions that change, leaving other DOM nodes untouched. It even goes as far as making sure that DOM nodes are re-used while sorting collections etc. (collections rendered using the `ng-repeat` directive). Obviously AngularJS is far more than just a templating engine!

Comment: Then you are doing something wrong with KO

Comment: I agree with Anders. Knockout renders only the changes, you must be doing something wrong. Show your code and add a jsfidde to demonstrate.

Answer (score 1):

the With binding and the Template binding will rerender the entire content if you change the object reference to a new one. You should instead only change the state on the observables that have changed.

My guess is that you are in a CRUD scenario and receive an entire new model from backend? If this is the case and you dont want to rerender the entire view use the mapping plugin, it will update the observables on the old object and thus not rerender the entire  view.

```
I clarified my answer with a fiddle
```

http://jsfiddle.net/G4ZME/1/